# function call after page reload, with onbeforeload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, page-refresh, onbeforeunload

i am doing page refresh with onbeforeload

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return 'You are going to release the document!';
    }


    window.onunload = function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/controller/function',
          async: false,
          type: 'get',
          complete: function(data){

          }
        });     
    }
```

here the issue is, when i am refresh/reload the page this ajax actually happens only after the page reload, because in this ajax call i updates one flag in database, but when reload this page, that database update only happen after this page reload, because i am getting the old value after refresh, not updated value, is there any way to do that before reload?

Comment: *"when i am refresh/reload the page this ajax actually happens only after the page reload"* Not with the code above. **If** the browser lets you do synchronous ajax during `unload`, it'll do it before the refresh, not after. (But synchronous ajax in an `unload` event is both unreliable and poor UX. The user left/refreshed, they shouldn't be left sitting there while your ajax runs on the page they left/refreshed.)

Comment: Not to mention that user could leave page after losing internet connection or power outage etc and ajax will never be sent

Comment: But if i didn't put that async:false, that ajax call will not happen. so how to handle that